# How can we add/update a image path with own code without using addImageToMediaGallery()

Tags: magento-1.8, php, product-images, image

Can we update a own defined product image path to database, I am adding products with own custom code.I want to add image database  without help of

```
->addImageToMediaGallery()
```

Is it doable??
without using  this line i want to add direct path // external url to database

```
# media gallery initialization
->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array (), 'values' => array ())) 
# assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery
->addImageToMediaGallery('xxx/my.jpg', array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), false, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento keep images path in `media/catalog/product/` then if your image name is `'sampleimage.jpg'` then magento creates a directory name taken as the first and second letter from the image name then create like below.

```
media/catalog/product/s/a/sampleimage.jpg
```

So, if you want to change the magento images path, this will lead you to change core functionality.Changing core functionality for this purpose is not advisable from me.

Edit:
for your question,

you can add own path, then if you use `addImageToMediaGallery($file,$mediaAttribute = null,$move = false,$exclude = true)` method for saving image, the `$move` parameter is the exact one you need to change for your problem.

```
if it is true then it move the image from the file path you have given.
if it is false then it copies the image.(so image remains in filepath).
```

**Edit:**

This [QUESTION](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/how-to-import-gallery-images-with-csv) WILL HELP YOU.

Comment: No,No need to upload / move the image, i want to update the database only.directly, I am inserting products using this http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/, the problem is that i want to upload the image path only as i have not the image,Because the image will be display from other server

Comment: Oh ok,[This link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/importing-product-images) will help you.

Comment: This is for  Magento Go

Comment: Sorry , is there any another way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The images are stored in the table catalog_product_entity_media_gallery (for gallery) and in catalog_product_entity_varchar (for image, small image and thumbnauil)

You can change them using direct db queries [like this](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/)