# Small Images on site appear in reverse order

Tags: database, product-images, stores, image-preview

I upload a .csv file to magento that looks like:

[image]
[image]

When the small_image appear on the website, for whatever reason, the final picture is the one being displayed. I was able to navigate using the GUI and pull up this page which showed that the radio button for the final image is the one that is clicked.

[image]

If I click the radio button for small_image on the first picture, than I am able to restore the website to the display that I originally intended.

Does anyone know how to default to this in the .csv? I would hate to have to go through 100s/1000s of items individually to accomplish this.

Thank You

Note: The sort_order column was added as a "workaround" to try and solve this issue. However, it hasn't solved anything.

Answer (score 2):

In your CSV, amend the last line and set the `small_image` and `thumbnail` values appropriately. (I suppose you are just updating the same product four times in order to assign four images at a time)

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you saying that the final line in the csv should be the image that I want to appear first? If so, it will appear first but will be numbered on the website as the fourth image. In addition, I AM updating the same product four times in order to assign four images. I was told to do it this way -- is this how it should be done?

Comment: If you've already uploaded all your gallery images, you can just upload a CSV with the SKU and the relevant values for each `image`, `small_image` and `thumbnail` and it should update your catalogue accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by gallery images? Are you saying, after I've uploaded all the photos in the way I already have, upload a CSV that has one picture per item?

Answer (score 2):

When you update an "image" "small_image" or "thumbnail" it is added to the product and selected as you can see from the radio buttons as per below, your next row will then be imported and selected removing the selection from the first. The way you have it setup the last row for that product will have the selected images.

[image]

It's been along time since I did any importing in Magento But I think there is a media_gallery / media_image attribute to import the extra images and then just use "image", "small_image" and "thumbnail" for the images you want to be selected.
This stack exchange answer may help : [how to import gallery images with csv](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/how-to-import-gallery-images-with-csv#answer-1188)

Comment: I'm not sure how to post a picture to my changes, so I will post it as an answer that I will eventually delete. Does this look similar to what you meant? (See below)

Answer (score 1):

Does this look correct? (In response to the answer above from @James Anelay)

[image]